# Need to trigger/request a FileStack Workflow in PHP

Tags: php, workflow, filestack

I need to request a workflow on filestack... BUT:

a) the only examples on the internet on how to do this are in javascript and i need to do this on PHP (on server side)

b) the official PHP API of Filestack on github, dont provide anything about workflow's

I got in contact with Filestack support and they told me that currently the only way to request a workflow is using javascript.

Does anyone had the same problem?

Does someone know's how to "fool" filestack javascript API and reproduce the same request using PHP and Curl ?

Thanks!

PS: here's the link on filestack website:

https://www.filestack.com/docs/concepts/workflows/

Answer (score 0):

i just receive an answer from the second level support at filestack...we can access the url directly:

http://cdn.filestackcontent.com/%3Capikey%3E/store=workflows:%5B%3Cworkflow_id%3E%5D/%3CURL-OF_THE_FILE_THAT_YOU_WANT-TO_VALIDATE_VIA_WORKFLOW%3E